# Why is NSLookup returning more than one record?

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, dns

I am doing an NSlookup on my OSX machine and getting more than one record.

```
174.0.100.24.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer my-machine.domain1.domainname.com.

174.0.100.24.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer nintendo\0323ds.domain1.domainname.com.
```

What the hell? I have set my own domain name, why the hell does the DNS server think my machine is a nintendo 3ds?

I have tried reseting the cache using:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

and

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

I am running 10.9.5 maybe I am not resetting the cache correctly?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache? It may have been that before?

Comment: @EdG maybe I am not resetting the cache correctly for 10.9.5?

Comment: I assume you got those commands from [here](http://www.ihash.eu/2013/10/clear-dns-cache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/)?

Comment: @EdG no different site and the order of the command were different, but still the same result.

Comment: Posted an answer

Comment: `nslookup` does not use the OS resolver (and, as such, no cache or anything) but talks DNS directly.

Comment: @DanielB so you are suggesting that the issue is on the DNS server correct? Is there a command similar to nslookup that uses the OS resolver?

Comment: Yes. Without further details about it, providing an answer is not possible. Network Utility, perhaps. It comes with OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the string of comments, give this a try and then reboot

```
dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches
```

Comment: so discoveryutil appears to be a yosemite thing, but I did attempt the restart still with no luck.

Comment: That's a bit odd, I've heard that works on a security update of Mavericks! Oh well... that is weird. I'll look into it a bit more.